# Return Observable from RxJS filter() predicate

Tags: filter, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

Is there an operator in RxJS that works like `filter()` but accepts a predicate that allows returning an Observable? So when the Observable returned by the predicate emits an event `filter()` decides whether event from the original source should be discarded or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I'd do it like the following:

```
const Observable = Rx.Observable;
const Subject = Rx.Subject;

let subject = new Subject();

source = Observable.from([1,2,3,4])
  .flatMap(val => subject
    .withLatestFrom(Observable.of(val), (_, val) => val)
    .filter(val => val % 2 == 0)
  );

source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

subject.next(null);
setTimeout(() => {
  subject.next(null);
}, 1000);
```

I wrapped each value with another Observable and [`withLatestFrom`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-withLatestFrom) operator that emits only when its source emits. In my case the source is `subject` so I have full control over it. Then there's `filter()` that can filter whatever you want.

Although, I wonder if there's any easier solution...

This prints only two values and after 1s another two because I called `subject.next(null);` inside the `setTimeout` callback:

```
2
4
2
4
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/gasumiz/10/edit?js,console

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm that the demo behaves as I expected, though the code indeed looks a bit too involved for this scenario. I'll try to apply it within next couple of hours to the real use case I have in mind and then I'll come back to you to let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using two `switchMap` operators:

```
const animals$ = from(['cat', 'dog', 'fish']).pipe(switchMap(animal => {

    // call webservice to determine if the animal is a mammal or not
    // this returns an observable boolean (i.e. a predicate)
    // this could be any Observable<boolean> of course
    const isMammal$: Observable<boolean> = webService.isMammal(animal);

    // when we get the result back if it's true then return the 
    // original 'animal' string (by creating a new observable with of()) 
    // if it isn't an animal then return EMPTY, which has the same effect as filtering it out
    return isMammal$.pipe(switchMap(isMammal => isMammal ? of(animal) : EMPTY));
}))
```